# Button not showing up on screen Android Application

Tags: android, button, show

I have created an application where users can send and share text that they have input, if they click the send button, the text that they input will be displayed, if they click the share button, the application opens up a list of sharing methods (GMail, Messaging etc..), what I want is though, to allow the users to view there text and then share it, hwoever, when the user clicks send and it goes to the file activity_display, the text shows, but the button does not. Any ideas why? Could you fix this? Here's the code;

activity_display_message.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="shareMessage"
android:layout_below="@+id/text_view"
android:text="test" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MAIN PROBLEM: Button Share does not show.

EDIT: I suspect I may need to include something to this file, here's the code, any help?

DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using RelativeLayout you need to specify where to layout your views. Try this for example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="shareMessage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_view"
    android:text="test" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it still doesn't show the button, I have updated the code above.

Comment: I don't see "layout_below" option

Answer (score 1):

you are using relative layout. use linear layout instead. this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative layout. The objects are overlapping because you have not set them up to be LeftOf or Below or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your button with:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:onClick="shareMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_share" />
```

And TextView with this:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```